How dismiss from a SwiftUI view back to a UIKit view controller in an iOS app?
Would like to return to my presenting UIKit View Controller after pressing the back button on my SwiftUI View (presented via a HostingViewController) and present the full view.
This is for UIKit viewcontroller
    let chooseProfileView = ChooseProfileView()
    // Wrap the SwiftUI view in a UIHostingController
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: chooseProfileView)
    hostingController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    // Present the UIHostingController modally
    self.present(hostingController, animated: true, completion: nil)


The dismiss environment value supports dismissing to a UIKit view controller too.
For example, here is a view with a back button:
struct SomeSwiftUIView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is a SwiftUI View")
            Button("Back") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}

You can present it from UIKit like this:
let swiftUIView = SomeSwiftUIView()
let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
hostingController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(hostingController, animated: true, completion: nil)

and pressing the back button will dismiss it as expected.

presentationMode environment value supports dismiss the SwiftUI view.
For example, here is a view with a back button:
its support for iOS 14.0 and above
struct ChooseProfileView: View {
   @SwiftUI.Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

   var body: some View {
    
     VStack {
        Text("This is a SwiftUI View")
        Button(action: {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            Image("HomeScreenBackButton")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .imageScale(.large)
        }
     }
   }
}

Note:: It supports iOS 15.0 and higher - use this code
@Environment(.dismiss) var dismiss
