How to resolve 'self' used before 'super.init' call when using UIHostingController with SwiftUI's View?
I have the following code, which I want my SwiftUI to execute UIKit closed function.
struct FlashcardView: View {
    var closeAction: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("This is the main content")
                .navigationTitle("Your Title")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: { closeAction() }) {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

class FlashcardHostingController: UIHostingController<FlashcardView> {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        let rootView = FlashcardView(closeAction: { [weak self] in
            self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: rootView)
    }
}

However, I am getting compiler error
'self' used before 'super.init' call

May I know what is a good way to resolve such an issue? Thanks.

You shouldn't need to do this unless the actual logic in closeAction is more complicated. SwiftUI can dismiss the UIHostingController out of the box. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/78952211/5133585

Give the action an empty default value then set it separately in the init
struct FlashcardView: View {
    var closeAction: () -> Void = { }
    //...
}

class FlashcardHostingController: UIHostingController<FlashcardView> {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: FlashcardView())

        self.rootView.closeAction = { [weak self] in self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }
    }
}

